# jenkins workflow plugin MissingMethodException

Tags: jenkins-workflow

I am trying out the jenkins workflow plugin and have started the tutorial https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md

I am using jenkins 1.628 CloudBees Build Flow 0.18 tomcat 7.0.56  java 1.8.0_25  with all the latest workflow plugins freshly installed.

When I try the first example

```
echo 'hello from Workflow'
```

I get this error

```
ERROR: Failed to run DSL Script
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: 
com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.FlowDelegate.echo() is applicable for 
argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [hello from Workflow]
```

If I change the code to

```
println 'hello from Workflow'
```

the job runs.

If I try the next example

```
node { 
    git url: 'https://github.com/jglick/simple-maven-project-with-tests.git'  
    def mvnHome = tool 'M3' 
    sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -B verify"
}
```

this error occurs

```
ERROR: Failed to run DSL Script groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
No signature of method: 
com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.FlowDelegate.node() 
is applicable for argument types: (Script1$_run_closure1) values: 
[Script1$_run_closure1@1dbe8f29]
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to uninstall the CloudBees Build Flow plugin. It is only the workflow plugins such as Workflow: Aggregator 1.10 that are needed.

Comment: BTW I filed [build-flow-plugin PR 65](https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-flow-plugin/pull/65) which might help reduce future confusion.